# Animations disappear in iOS application after some time

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, ios7

After several minutes running all animations in my application disappeared, even system animations like alert animation and UINavigationController animations. What can be the issue?

P.S. I dont use `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled]` anywhere.

Comment: How are you animating? Are you using `removeOnCompletion=NO`?

Comment: Any attempt to answer this question would be guesswork

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the answer is - system sometimes disables animations, and, normally, it enables them back on. But in my case, for some reason, it failed to set them back enabled. And this happens only during transitions between UIViewControllers. What I came up with, is to reset `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]` after every transition.

Comment: what do you mean "after every transition" ? How is that a solution .. ?

Comment: Well, in my case system was disabling animations during transitions between controllers. This is not the best solution, but I just couldn't find anything better