# (IOS7) Animation action disappears sometime

Tags: ios, animation

I've met this problem since upgrade to ios7. 
Sometimes I run my app (build to go or just run it), all animation goes away! 
For example, viewController pushes or pops back. 
Any one knows why? When I continue running it, the animation comes back sometimes. It has driven me crazy!!

Comment: I've experienced the same problem... I will keep my eyes on your question :D my hunch would be about memory issues, but i'm  probabily wrong

Comment: I have also the same problem here

Comment: What is the device you  are using guys?

Comment: It happens to me on the ipad2, but it has happened also on the simulator

Comment: I haven't met it on simulator, just on device. My device is iPhone 4s with IOS 7.0.3. I'm sure it's nothing about the memory issue.

Comment: @LeverkusenFan why are you so sure that it not a memory issue? I am not saying it is but did you try to run the app on a different device.

Comment: I've monitoring the memory usage during my app running and found that when it lose animations, the app take about 50M memory. When the animation comes back, the app take about 60+M memory.  It's just several cases but I think it tells me something. I'll try to reappear this on the other devices and update the progress.

Comment: I know it´s hard to test, but could it be due to calling UIKit functionalities from another thread different that the main one?

Comment: Case 1: iPhone4S with IOS7.0.3, xCode 4.6.2,  animation disappears sometime.   Case 2: iPhone4S with IOS6, xCode 4.6.2, animation never disappears.  Case 3: Simulator with IOS7, xCode5.0 animation disappears sometime. Case 4: Simulator with IOS6, xCode5.0 animation never disappears. So, I think it's irrelative with xCode, codes, project setting but IOS version.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me on the iPhone6(IOS8.3 12F70) and the Xcode version is 6.3(6D570)

After running across the problem, I use the view debugging tool to capture
the view hierarchy. Check the value of `[UIView areAnimationsEnabled]` in debugging console. It returns false/nil. After setting it enabled through UIView's class method `setAnimationsEnabled:`, The animations come back again.

I don't yet have any idea about what set the animation disabled. And I'm sure my code doesn't do it. Even if I setting the symbolic break point, it's hard to chase the source. Because of a whole bunch of UIKit methods call the `setAnimationsEnabled:`, such as setting an image to UIImageView's image property, status bar showing and hiding, and a lot more.

Here an answer to a similar question [Animations disappear in iOS application after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19246991/1389917), hope it will helps!